# Web scraping of an online dictionary

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet

1.I made a web scraper of an online dictionary. It scrapes and saves to a text file definitions and examples of sentences of words in a list. I want to make this scraper publicly available on GitHub. This scraper will be free of charge. Is it legal?
There is nothing said about it in Terms and Conditions https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/terms-and-conditions.

2.Is it legal to scrape and download sounds of words (.mp3 file) from oxfordlearnersdictionaries?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=scraping

Comment: Regarding dictionary it's tricky, since dictionary cannot be copyrighted https://www.quora.com/Can-a-dictionary-be-copyrighted . They copy sentences from other books in dictionaries.

Comment: @homievk "dictionary cannot be copyrighted" This significantly misstates the way that copyright law applies to dictionaries, and the best answer at the link reaches the opposite conclusion with good authority to support it.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on which jurisdiction you are in.

- **Operating** this scraper and **using** the resulting data set could be a violation of copyright laws in some countries. The copyright status of databases like a dictionary is where details of the implementation of various conventions differs.
- **Writing** and **uploading** the scraper might conceivably violate 'hacking tools' laws, but this is much less likely.
- You might be in violation of the terms of service of the site, which is a civil matter.

Comment: I found on their website "no materials may otherwise be copied, modified, published, broadcast or otherwise distributed without our prior written permission". It means scraping is not legal?

Comment: @homievk, it means they are explicitly denying the permission to scrape for re-use by you. What that means depends on your local laws.

Comment: Generally, violating terms of service [is not a crime in the US](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/07/court-violating-terms-service-not-crime-bypassing) but circumventing technological barriers to access a website might be (and the bar for this is quite low e.g. changing your IP address to get around a ban). Without knowing exactly how the scraper works, it's hard to know if there might be a case.